# What quantity of coconut oil should be substituted for butter in a brownie mix?

Tags: substitutions, oil, butter, brownies, coconut

I want to substitute coconut oil for the butter in a brownie mix but I don't know how much to use. The recipe calls for 3/4 stick of melted butter. How much coconut oil should I use?

Comment: How did the final result turn out?  I'm looking for a good diary-free brownie recipe.  Did this work with the coconut oil finally? Is there a specific preference to using coconut oil vs vegetable/grapeseed oil?

Answer (score 11):

Butter is about 80% milkfat, and 20% water, more or less.

3/4 stick is 6 tablespoons.

You should be able to substitute six tablespoons of coconut oil one to one.  It should be well within the tolerance of the recipe.

If you really want to account for the water, you would do about 5 tbl of coconut oil, and 1 tbl of liquid.

Comment: Posted despite your answer, because I had already typed half of mine when yours appeared

Comment: I am sure we were typing at the same time, no worries.  Plus you gave European style answers (and milkfat percentage), and I gave US style.

Answer (score 10):

Butter is 83% fat, 17% water (we can ignore the milk solids in this case). Instead of 90 g butter, you can use 75 g coconut oil and 15 g more liquid (e.g. milk, or whatever the recipe specifies). There will be a slight difference in texture in the finished product, but nothing to worry about.